# Dapp Development using Truffle framework getting error

Tags: dapp-development, truffle

I am using truffle framework, which has pudding functionality. I have compiled the same contract on the both Dapps and deployed it on the one Dapp. Now i am trying to access it from another Dapp using the truffle method `contractname.at(contractaddress)` and when i call the functions of the contracts, it returns me the error

> "Uncaught BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number."

Same error for all the functions returning string, "0x" for the functions returning address. Don't know what to do??

Comment: Consider testnet using geth

Comment: Can you please include full stacktrace and related source code to the question.

Comment: that's little difficult, i can tell you whatever you require @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39725/discussion-on-question-by-aniket-dapp-development-using-truffle-framework-gettin).